# How to implement reliable UDP to transfer files quickly?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp

I want to transfer some files from one point to another. Files are sensitive so transfer has to be reliable, but if I use TCP to transfer files than the speed gets slow.

How do I create a reliable version of UDP that will transfer files quickly?

What I am doing is sending an acknowledgement for every received packet. But it is reducing my transfer speed.

Is there any way that exists without sending an acknowledgment for every received packet? Can I somehow keep track of lost packets efficiently and request those packets only?

Note:: I am sending a sequence number with every packet

Comment: so you want to implement by yourself TCP using UDP ? Do you think you will do that better and faster than TCP does ?

Comment: Anything you do to solve this will make the network slower. Just accept it. You need either an ACK-based protocol or a NACK-based protocol.

Comment: is there any way to mix TCP and UDP protocol to get the result. What if I use both protocols in the application layer? How would it go?

Comment: Badly............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you could put a count value in each packet and if you received a packet that skips a value then you know that you've lost one or more and could request a resend.

However, you're starting to implement the functionality of TCP by coding for packet loss. Is there a reason why you couldn't implement that instead?

Certainly if I was transferring sensitive data I wouldn't choose UDP myself.

Comment: I am trying to send the data as fast as possible with any loss. Would TCP transfer be as fast as UDP?

Comment: Which is your most important metric? Speed or reliability of transfer? Typically UDP is used when you don't care too much about packet loss say because the data packets sent are repeatedly sent and some loss is acceptable e.g. video or audio. TCP is slightly slower but is reliable. Another point is that UDP is connection less and so  can broadcast to multiple destinations where as TCP requires a new connection for each destination.

Comment: most important is reliability and I want to speed it up as much as possible(faster than TCP) is there any way to do that?

Comment: In principle, TCP can fully saturate a link (i.e. you can use pretty much 100% of the available bandwidth). However, that's only the case if there is no other communication on the same link. Multiple TCP connections for instance will automatically adjust so that each gets a fair share of the link. In the presence of UDP traffic, the performance of a TCP connection can drop significantly (UDP isn't as "nice" as TCP). So yes, using UDP can improve performance, but you'll have to sacrifice reliability.